# How to extract a specific line from a webpage in c#

Tags: c#, html-parsing

```
 HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + "msg");
    HttpWebResponse myres = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myres.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        pageContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    if (pageContent.Contains("find"))
    {

     display = "done";

    }
```

currently what this code does is check if "find" exists on a url and display done if it is present
What I want is to display the whole line or para which contains "find".

So like instead display="done" I want to store the line which contains find in display

Comment: HTML pages don't have lines. Whitespace outside tags is ignored and an entire minified page may have no newlines at all. Even if it did, newlines are simply ignored even inside tags.That's why `<br>` is necessary

Comment: If you want to find a specific element you'll have to use an HTML parser like AngleSharp or HTMLAgilityPack and identify the element using an XPath or CSS selector expression

Answer (score 1):

HTML pages don't have lines. Whitespace outside tags is ignored and an entire minified page may have no newlines at all. Even if it did, newlines are simply ignored even inside tags.That's why `<br>` is necessary. If you want to find a specific element you'll have to use an HTML parser like [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and identify the element using an XPath or CSS selector expression.

Copying from the landing page examples:

```
var url = $"https://www.google.com/search?q={msg}" ;
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

var value = doc.DocumentNode
 .SelectNodes("//div[@id='center_col']")
 .First()
 .Attributes["value"].Value;
```

What you put in `SelectNodes` depends on what you want to find.

One way to test various expressions is to open the web page you want in a browser, open the browser's Developer Tools and start searching in the Element inspector. The search functionality there accepts XPath and CSS selectors.